# status 143 error in Heroku for MEAN JS app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack, meanjs

This app works fine in development locally but breaks in production. Heroku docs are not much help. Here are the logs. Any ideas? What other file would you need to see in order to gather required info?

```
2015-07-08T19:43:20.171096+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-08T19:43:20.171178+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-07-08T19:43:20.122153+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by 
2015-07-08T19:43:20.122153+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 6c5a2eb by 
2015-07-08T19:43:20.229087+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-07-08T19:43:22.728050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-07-08T19:43:23.765850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js`
2015-07-08T19:43:24.379905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-07-08T19:43:25.625194+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-07-08T19:43:25.625166+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.074341+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
2015-07-08T19:43:26.198885+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2015-07-08T19:43:26.075391+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
2015-07-08T19:43:26.217727+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-07-08T19:43:26.217964+00:00 app[web.1]:    assets: {
2015-07-08T19:43:26.217842+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/env/production.js:6
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221411+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221413+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221415+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221416+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221422+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.217966+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^^^^^^
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221407+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221419+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/config.js:14:2)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221417+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221420+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221410+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
2015-07-08T19:43:26.227411+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2015-07-08T19:43:26.221423+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2015-07-08T19:44:23.838412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-07-08T19:44:23.838726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-07-08T19:44:24.855873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-07-08T19:44:24.868069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-08T19:44:24.869307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-08T19:44:28.879129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js`
2015-07-08T19:44:31.286601+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-07-08T19:44:31.286625+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-07-08T19:44:32.195270+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
2015-07-08T19:44:32.196656+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
2015-07-08T19:44:32.527042+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2015-07-08T19:44:32.551018+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/env/production.js:6
2015-07-08T19:44:32.551021+00:00 app[web.1]:    assets: {
2015-07-08T19:44:32.551022+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^^^^^^
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557599+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557603+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557606+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557604+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557607+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557609+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557610+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557612+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/config.js:14:2)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557613+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557614+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.557616+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2015-07-08T19:44:32.560998+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2015-07-08T19:44:32.550675+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-07-08T19:45:18.337947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=docketing.herokuapp.com request_id=5ada4d19-6535-4e63-9d6b-1d74266f759a fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-08T19:45:29.464868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-07-08T19:45:29.464980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-07-08T19:45:30.260616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-08T19:45:30.232546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-07-08T19:45:31.540913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=87ac9f5f-74f2-4010-ada0-38481ec6246e fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-08T19:45:31.907041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=53a948f8-a845-4e92-946a-e9706c03d4bd fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-07-08T19:46:41.940958+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 21adb89 by eric.gnplaw@gmail.com
2015-07-08T19:46:41.940988+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by eric.gnplaw@gmail.com
2015-07-08T19:46:42.013531+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-08T19:46:42.013554+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-07-08T19:46:42.619968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-08T19:46:45.258343+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js`
2015-07-08T19:46:46.710824+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-07-08T19:46:46.710847+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-07-08T19:46:47.136829+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
2015-07-08T19:46:47.247287+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2015-07-08T19:46:47.137695+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
2015-07-08T19:46:48.259485+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 56609
2015-07-08T19:46:48.741917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-07-08T19:46:49.336931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=ecc3844e-2fab-45ab-a809-5db0b258b666 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=86ms status=200 bytes=1349
2015-07-08T19:46:49.457576+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=8353bda8-7869-4f8e-a1a1-2e4fea9e7e9c fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=20179
2015-07-08T19:46:49.488707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=fd0582a1-6fd2-4588-9f73-8b02b6549850 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=7204
2015-07-08T19:46:49.539287+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=54b36b9e-02e6-4711-a718-2d47579ea9c8 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=7179
2015-07-08T19:46:49.571068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=9aff059d-2f86-4d3b-8a43-8e8b7a9cd4bf fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=11722
2015-07-08T19:46:49.596999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.min.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=84588746-3b29-4741-8767-0b808c8b610d fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=8882
2015-07-08T19:46:49.631952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=e14a676e-b114-432c-bfac-2bde20a4abf4 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=17765
2015-07-08T19:46:50.461782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=9d8981bf-e17a-4875-8830-e52100300780 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=2229
2015-07-08T19:46:50.463911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=2785b451-07bc-4ce4-b9f5-a376b2338de5 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=8366
2015-07-08T19:46:50.469210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=b9c125e6-5871-4f0c-9dc3-b9d293dd2354 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=3184
2015-07-08T19:46:50.476196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular/angular.min.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=d6646cf0-4e9b-4b10-a46b-aed279dbe8b5 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=38ms status=200 bytes=40444
2015-07-08T19:46:50.626750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=c31158bd-0091-4569-a456-61f807878872 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=32415
2015-07-08T19:46:50.478453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" host=dock.herokuapp.com request_id=7e8b068a-e9ac-4643-9943-13aef979b590 fwd="65.88.88.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=16441
```

Comment: a wild guess, check both productio.js and developement.js for any problem.